# Can't retrive data from Azure Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio, azure

So I'm connected to an Azure SQL Database in Visual Studio, but for some reason I can't seem to be able to retrieve anything from the database itself, it keeps loading infinity.

Here's what I see in the SQL Server Object Explorer:
[image: endless loading loop next to the database, system table and tables]

If I right click the database and View Code it says it couldn't retrieve the definition of the database from the server.

[image: Error within database .sql file]

If I go to the Data Connections within the Server Explorer I can see the database and I can see the tables, but I still can't see any data or definitions, getting the same error as the previous one.

I've tried reinstalling multiple versions of Visual Studio 2017 and 2019, I've tried enabling/disabling firewalls, windows defenders, anything that might interfere with the connection, but still no success.

I have tried opening it on a different computer, and it works, it just doesn't seem to work on my laptop which is more than capable of handling this kind of work.

Comment: (edit, seen your connection succeeds) Have you tried installing Sql Server Management Studio and connecting to the azure DB from that? SSMS might give you a better definition of the error being encountered. Might be that the LOGIN in the DB does not have REFERENCE permission then it will not be able to retrieve the table definition?

Comment: Hi, yes I tried and It gives this error: https://i.imgur.com/lpf7CrE.png

Comment: also, when I try to execute our Asp WebApi project, the Api returns this error:
[pastebin](https://pastebin.com/D0NvPSFd)

Comment: Without doing too much of the googling for you, if it works on one machine and not another then it's normally an client level issue. Errors like the ones you've found are normally linked to firewalls, connection errors etc. if your machine that works and the machine that does not work are on the same network then something on the machine is stopping the connection, like AntiVirus software or firewalls

Comment: that was my guess too, but even with the firewall disabled and antivirus, I still got the same errors... I already tried to create a new local windows user account, and same errors... And in safe boot/safe mode too...

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this simple solution, it worked for me long back.

Make sure you check the "Save my password" checkbox when you add new database connection view picture.

[image]

Also add `Persist Security Info=True;` to my connection string in web.config.

Please try and see if it helps.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately didn't work too...
At this point we're mitigating this issue using a local copy of the DB